# php variable inside another variable

Tags: php

I have a variable that im define with another variable and some text.

```
$title = "New Amsbrook School" //demo text
$message = "$title just added, Congrats!";
```

Echoing of $message returns New just added, Contrats!

Problem is if there is a space in $title, it breaks and doesnt show the rest of the contents.

Comment: You know, adding the semicolon to the question makes your question make no sense. Code as it is now will run correctly.

Comment: Byron is correct; don't fix your code after the fact or we will all be confused whenever someone stumbles upon this question later. I removed the semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs a semi-colon at the end of the first line, before the comment.

Answer (score 3):

You missed a semicolon at the end of $title string ;-)

Comment: +1 - nice, I was scratching my head trying to figure out what the heck he was doing wrong.  Figured it had to be something simple like that :)

Comment: I'm stocked that it even got parsed. Patrick, make sure you have error-reporting turned on while developing. It will point this stuff out immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Works when i define the variable as the following.

```
$title = urlencode($row['title']);
```